# MSAL - No provider for BroadcastService

Tags: angular, msal-angular

I'm trying to add MSAL to an existing old angular v6 project, so I ran :

```
npm install @azure/msal-angular@1.1.2 --save
npm install 'msal@1.4.4' --save
```

And I added the code as usual to app.component.ts and app.module.ts, nothing special with the http interceptor and a factory for each configs.
It compiles fine, but when I run it I get this in the console :

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> BroadcastService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> BroadcastService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for BroadcastService!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1062)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8369)
    at _createClass (core.js:8422)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8386)
```

Any idea on what I could have forgotten? As far as I can tell BroadcastService is supposed to come from msal itself, not sure why it's missing.

Comment: Just adding this as a comment as it was one of the first search results that popped up: Obviously the name changed from BroadcastService to MsalBroadcastService in the latest version. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Works better if you add the MsalModule to the imports .. that's my bad, sorry.